# Error while installing silverlight 5 package in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

i'm having an error while installing silverlight 5 toolkit saying that "This installation package couldn't be opened contact the application vendor to verify that is a valid windows installer package"

Comment: Please, provide more info about environment, etc.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1 pro and visual studio 2013

Comment: Windows Phone Silverlight is different from Silverlight 5. You cannot use the Silverlight 5 toolkit on a Windows Phone. For Windows Phone 8 you can use the similar Windows Phone Toolkit.

Comment: Could you send any link for Beginner's Guide ( step by step ) for windows phone 8 app ?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the current `Silverlight` version and follow the steps [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/updates-to-silverlight-wont-install-and-cant/d77eab76-c443-4234-9e8b-faa15a3a0d94), which provides a work around for this issue. Or else try doing a `cleanup` a broken `Silverlight. installation.

[clean up a broken Silverlight installation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rpomeroy/archive/2008/06/10/how-to-manually-clean-up-a-bad-silverlight-installation.aspx)